# Symfony2: Change choices with ajax and validation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Scenario: I have a form with 2 selects. When user selects something from the first select, the second select gets populated with new values. This part works fine.

But the form does not get validated since it contains some choices that are not allowed in the initial form.

Form:

```
<?php

class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    private $category;

    public function __construct($category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'foo' => 'foo',
                'bar' => 'bar'
            )
        );

        $builder->add('template', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->loadChoices()
        );
    }

    private function loadChoices()
    {
        // load them from DB depending on the $this->category
    }
}
```

Initially the category is `foo`. So the templates for foo get loaded and set as choices. But if the user selects `bar`, the bar templates get loaded. But the form still has the foo choices and does not validate.

What is the best way to solve this?

One way I found was to just reinitiate the form in the controller:

```
<?php

$form = $this->createForm(new MyType());

if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
    if ($request->request->has($form->getName())
        && isset($request->request->get($form->getName())['category'])) {
            $form = $this->createForm(new MyType($request->request->get($form->getName())['category']));
    }

    // ...
}
```

This works, but I cannot test it because it throws `IllegalArgumentException` when setting the value and just assumes default. Is there any better solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to set validation groups for each set of options you have to validate? Then, you can call the validator service only on the group that is relevant for you. http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think u have to use Events to manage this, which is more correct way

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'foo' => 'foo',
            'bar' => 'bar'
        )
    ));

    $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();

    // function to add 'template' choice field dynamically 
    $func = function (FormEvent $e) use ($ff) {
        $data = $e->getData();
        $form = $e->getForm();
        if ($form->has('template')) {
            $form->remove('template');
        }

        $cat = isset($data['category'])?$data['category']:null;

        // here u can populate ur choices in a manner u do it in loadChoices
        $choices = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2');
        if ($cat == 'bar') {
            $choices = array('3' => '3', '4' => '4');
        }

        $form->add($ff->createNamed('template', 'choice', null, compact('choices')));
    };

    // Register the function above as EventListener on PreSet and PreBind
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, $func);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response here! I will check it today. :)

Comment: I was recommended this link for a similar problem I'm trying to get working (where I have been looking to use AJAX with `onChange` trigger). This way looks good, although I wanted to check before changing everything: Can this refresh the form to populate the `template` dropdown from database lookup when a Category has been selected without submitting the form?

Comment: why not. but you need a separate ajax endpoint to rerender form without submit logic etc. if i understand your question correctly