# Symfony2 form entity type with empty choices

Tags: symfony

I have the form
(buildForm method) :

```
    $builder->add('title')
        ->add('orders', 'entity', array(
            'property' => 'name', 
            'choices' => array(), 
            'multiple' => true, 
            'required' => false
        )
     )
```

as you can see option 'choices' is an empty array, that`s because I have too large list of entities. So I load a few options for my entity select on client side  via ajax  (ajaxChosen),
but after submitting my form I have a validation error on this field, because there are no such choices in array. How to solve this problem?

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321771/symfony2-change-choices-with-ajax-and-validation

Comment: it's interesting solution, but I thought solution would be more trivial

Comment: I agree, this is still a pain in the ass in Symfony 3

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY Please try to keep the swearing to a minimum and use only a professional language on SO.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is security on the select. This is so you can't submit any values that were not configured in the select.

Loading the choices in the form builder is a proper solution for this.