# Symfony2 - Dynamyc Select

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I was looking for some samples about Dynamic Ajax Select with Symfony2.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321771/symfony2-change-choices-with-ajax-and-validation/18830600#18830600) seemed the right solution to my doubts but something was wrong.

I've Simfony2.3 and i got an error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Automatic initialization is only supported on root forms. You should set the "auto_initialize" option to false on the field "template".") in UserRegBundle:Default/en:index.html.twig at line 8.
```

This is my *FormType.php*:

```
$builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'auto_initialize' => false,
        'choices' => array(
            'foo' => 'foo',
            'bar' => 'bar'
        )
    ));

    $ff = $builder->getFormFactory();

    // function to add 'template' choice field dynamically 
    $func = function (FormEvent $e) use ($ff) {
        $data = $e->getData();
        $form = $e->getForm();
        if ($form->has('template')) {
            $form->remove('template');
        }

        $cat = isset($data->category)?(string)$data->category:null;

        // here u can populate ur choices in a manner u do it in loadChoices
        $choices = array('ff' => 'ff', 'ee' => 'ee');
        if ($cat == '1') {
            $choices = array('dd' => 'dd', 'vv' => 'vv');
        }

        $form->add($ff->createNamed('template', 'choice', array('mapped' => false, 'auto_initialize' => false), compact('choices')));
    };

    // Register the function above as EventListener on PreSet and PreBind
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $func);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, $func);
```

Referred to the cited post, i put $data->category instead of $data['category'] because i got this array error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot use object of type var\www\...\Entity\User as array in /var/www/.../Bundle/MyBundle/Form/FormType.php line 101
```

Furtheremore i put this option into the createNamed

```
array('auto_initialize' => false)
```

because i got this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Automatic initialization is only supported on root forms. You should set the "auto_initialize" option to false on the field "template".") in UserRegBundle:Default/en:index.html.twig at line 8.
```

And now i faced this error and i don't have any idea about it:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/examples/test4/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceList.php line 458") in UserRegBundle:Default/en:index.html.twig at line 8.
```

Can anyone help me please? :/