# Symfony2- get data of auto populated drop down

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

I'm having two dropdowns which are not dependent on any entity. When I select the value of first one an ajax function is called to populate the second one which is done perfectly. But, the form after submission, always returns

```
type_name: ERROR: This value is not valid
```

My form looks like:

```
->add('type', 'choice', array(
                'empty_value' => "Select",
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 'One',
                    2 => 'Two'
                )
            ))
            ->add('type_name', 'choice', array(
                'empty_value' => "Select",
                'choices' => array(
                ),
            ))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: Change choices with ajax and validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321771/symfony2-change-choices-with-ajax-and-validation)

Answer (score 0):

This is because Symfony needs to know the choices beforehand in order to validate them correctly. Currently you are indicating that no choices are valid for your dropdown **type_name** as you are passing an empty array as **choices**.

Please check this answer for a detailed guide on how to implement dynamic choices and choice validation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374841/606104

Comment: I dont want them to be validated. I only want the value of the dropdwn

Comment: Implementing the code from the post I get this error :Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\profiles\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php