# How to structure Symfony to check for `onChange` dropdown fields?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

In my example, I have four entities that I want to use for a blog platform: <kbd>Owner</kbd> <kbd>Post</kbd> <kbd>User</kbd> <kbd>Location</kbd>

- An <kbd>Owner</kbd> can have multiple <kbd>Posts</kbd>
- A <kbd>Post</kbd> can have multiple <kbd>Users</kbd> and <kbd>Locations</kbd>

I am trying to create an admin form where I can select the <kbd>Owner</kbd> from a dropdown menu, that will refresh the form `onChange` to populate the dropdown menu of <kbd>Posts</kbd>.

When a <kbd>Post</kbd> is then selected, the form is again refreshed with form fields <kbd>Users</kbd> and <kbd>Locations</kbd> associated to that post. I can then either:

1. Update the existing entities with more information (eg User's date of birth or Location's GPS coordinates)
2. Create a new instance of either entity to attach to the <kbd>Post</kbd>

I've not included the <kbd>Location</kbd> entity and not included the namespaces/include statements as they would detract from my main question of how such an admin page should be coded in the controller/Formtypes (my attempts are as follows):

## Controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/adminposts", name="admin_posts")
*/
public function updatePostsAction(Request $request)
{
  $user = new User();
  $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($owner);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->persist($location);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
  }
  return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:adminupdate.post.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
  ));
}
```

## User Formtype:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
        $builder
             ->add('owner','entity',array(
                  'class'=>'AppBundle:Owner',
                  'choice_label'=>'username',
                  'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                             ->orderBy('d.username','ASC');
                  }))

             ->add('post','entity',array(
                  'class'=>'AppBundle:Post',
                  'choice_label'=>'posttext',
                  'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                             ->orderBy('d.postdate','ASC');
                  }))

             ->add('Firstname')
             ->add('Surname')
             ->add('DOB')
             ->getForm();
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Users',
        ));
  }

  public function getName()
  {
        return 'user';
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Ajax, have you given it a try ?

Comment: Thanks @Delphine, I had tried Ajax before starting with Symfony - to be honest, I'm not sure how I would implement Ajax in Symfony what with OO framework and twig templates. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe you can take a look here : [Symfony2: Change choices with ajax and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321771/symfony2-change-choices-with-ajax-and-validation) or follow my method :

In your UserType :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('owner','entity',array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:Owner',
                'choice_label'=>'username',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('o')
                        ->orderBy('o.username','ASC');
                }))

            ->add('Firstname')
            ->add('Surname')
            ->add('DOB');

        // Add listeners for Post field
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
    }


    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, $owner = null)
    {
        if($owner){
            $form->add('post','entity',array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:Post',
                'choice_label'=>'posttext',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er, $owner) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->join('p.owner', 'o')
                        ->where('o.id = :ownerID')
                        ->setParameter('ownerID', $owner->getID() )
                        ->orderBy('d.postdate','ASC');
                }));
        }
        else{
            $form->add('post','choice',array(
                'choice_label'=>'posttext',
                'empty_value' => '-- Choose --',
                'choices' => array())
            );
        }
    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $this->addElements($form, $data->getOwner());
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User user */
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $this->addElements($form, $user->getOwner());
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Users',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

I assume you know how to create an onChange Event in jQuery (I use to use it) and an ajax call.

Just for remind, in your view :

```
 {{ form_row(
        form.owner,
        {
            'attr': {               
                'data-owner-id': ""~form.owner.vars.id,
                'class': "change-posts-per-owner",
            }
        }
    ) }}
    {{ form_row(form.post) }}
    {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
    {{ form_row(form.surname) }}
    {{ form_row(form.DOB) }}
```

And your Ajax Script :

```
   $(document).on('change', 'select .change-posts-per-owner', function(){

       var ownerID = $(this).data("owner-id");

       $.ajax({
         url:  your_url,
         type: "GET", //or POST
         data: 'ownerID='+ownerID,
         dataType: 'JSON', //or html or whatever you want
         success:function(data) { 
          //Replace <option element in your select element for post list considering your dataType (type of response)
         }
      });

    }
```

You also can use `$.post()` or `$.get()` instead of explicit method `$.ajax();` 
I sugget you to use FOSJSRoutingBundle for indicating your url with `Routing.generate()` method.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer :) I'll be able to try this out at the weekend and get back to you!

Comment: Hi @Delphine, I've followed your code and I think it's all ok except I'm not sure how to structure the content of the `success:function(data) {}` section? Also, looking at the link to the other question you sent - that looks like it seems to do away with the need for Ajax and `onChange` events - would that be a simpler Symfony alternative if so?

Comment: I've been looking into the `FormEvents` from the Symfony documentation after the lead from @Delphine (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) - however it seems to say we should over *all* Posts for *all* Users in the response. However as each user can have thousands of Posts, this seems a little bit overkill compared to getting just the require data once a User has been chosen?

Comment: IN your Ajax call you should pass the ownerID (the one whom has been selected in the first select). That's what I code thanks to `$user->getOwner()`

Comment: And, the ajax method should return an array of Posts (owned by the owner you selected). You also should use Json format for this. 

In your controller (ajax method called) just get Posts related to owner passed. Return a Json response : `return new JsonResponse($posts)` so in your success ajax part just do : `$.each(data, function(k, v) { $(child).append('<option value="' + v[itemKey] + '">' + v[itemLabel] + '</option>'); }` where child is the second select box. PreSubmit event will validate the form by adding these posts to the form.

Comment: Hey Delphine, I truly appreciate your patience - I think I've got everything set up as you describe but unfortunately it's still not updating....but I'm certain it's an 'OP problem' and not your answer!

Comment: ...in case... the only error my IDE (PhpStorm) is flagging up is for the object `$owner` here: `->setParameter('ownerID', $owner->getID() )` (of the  `$form->add('post','entity'...` section) .... which I would have thought would have been ok because of the `if($owner)` condition...?

Comment: Ok ! I use the same IDE and I understand my mistake.. I forgot to add `$owner` parameter to the closure ! I'm going to update my answer but for clarity purpose you have to update by :  `'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er, $owner) {`

Comment: Thanks very much @Delphine ! I'll try from my side this evening. Makes sense though!

Comment: I'm still not getting the Ajax request being triggered unfortunately. I'm conscious this comment conversation is getting long so I've posted it as a new question here if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030619/why-isnt-this-ajax-call-capturing-the-onchange-event-in-symfony