# Why isn't this AJAX call capturing the onChange event in Symfony?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, onchange

I am trying to get this form to dynamically populate the select box with the related <kbd>Posts</kbd> once the <kbd>Owner</kbd> has been selected in the previous dropdown. My entities are all ok however I can't see what I'm missing in the below files that is stopping the Ajax requests from firing:

**My Controller**

```
/**
* @Route("/newUser", name="new_User")
*/
public function updatePostsAction(Request $request)
{
    $User = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $User);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($owner);
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->persist($location);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:adminupdate.post.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
* @Route("/newUserAjax", name="new_user_ajax")
*/
public function newUserAjaxAction(Request $request)
{
    return new JsonResponse($posts);
}
```

**My User FormType**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('Owners','entity',array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Owner',
            'placeholder' => '-- Choose --',
            'choice_label'=>'OwnerDesc',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->orderBy('d.OwnerDesc','ASC');
            }))

        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('surname')
        ->add('DOB');

    // Add listeners for Post field
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,   array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
    }


    protected function addElements(FormInterface $form, $Owner = null)
    {
    if($Owner){
        $form->add('Posts','entity',array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Post',
            'placeholder' => '-- Choose --',
            'choice_label'=>'PostDesc',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er, $Owner) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->join('e.Owner_id', 'd')
                    ->where('d.Ownerid = :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $Owner->getOwnerid() )
                    ->orderBy('e.Postdate','ASC');
            }));
    }
    else{
        $form->add('Posts','choice',array(
                'choice_label'=>'dummytext',
                'placeholder' => '-- Choose --',
                'choices' => array())
        );
    }
    }

    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    $this->addElements($form, $data->getOwners());
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
    /** @var User User */
    $User = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $this->addElements($form, $User->getOwners());
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
    ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
    return 'User';
    }
}
```

**My Twig template:**

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}

 {{ form_row(
             form.Owners,
             {
                 'attr':
                 {
                    'data-Owner-id': "form.Owner.vars.Owner_id",
                     'class': "change-posts-per-owner",
                 }
             }
 ) }}
{{ form_row(form.Posts, {'label' : 'Select Post of Owner'} ) }}
{{ form_row(form.firstname, {'label' : 'Firstname(s)'} ) }}
{{ form_row(form.surname, {'label' : 'Surname'} ) }}
{{ form_row(form.DOB, {'label' : 'Date of Birth'} ) }}
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**My ajax script:**

```
$(document).on('change', 'change-posts-per-owner', function(){

    var Ownerid = $(this).data("Owner-id");

    $.ajax({
    url:  "{{ path('new_User_ajax') }}",
    type: "GET", 
    data: 'Ownerid='+Ownerid,
    dataType: 'JSON', 

    error: function (data) {
        alert("An error ocurred." + data);
    },

    success:function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $(child).append('<option value="' + v[itemKey] + '">' + v[itemLabel] + '</option>');
        });
    }
    })
});
```

**UPDATE: including my entities**

<kbd>User</kbd> entity....

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /************************************************************
     * Variables
     ************************************************************/

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Userid", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Userid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dob", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $DOB;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Posts", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $Posts;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Owners", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $Owners;



    /************************************************************
     * Getters/setters
     ************************************************************/

    /************************************************************
     * Get Userid
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserid()
    {
        return $this->Userid;
    }

    /************************************************************
     * Get Posts
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->Posts;
    }

    /**
     * Set Posts
     * @param string $Posts
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPosts($Posts)
    {
        $this->Posts = $Posts;
        return $this ;
    }

    /************************************************************
     * Get Owners
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOwners()
    {
        return $this->Owners;
    }

    /**
     * Set Owners
     * @param string $Owners
     * @return User
     */
    public function setOwners($Owners)
    {
        $this->Posts = $Owners;
        return $this ;
    }





    /************************************************************
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        return $this;
    }


    /************************************************************
     * Get nameSurname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameSurname()
    {
        return $this->nameSurname;
    } 

    /**
     * Set nameSurname
     *
     * @param string $nameSurname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setNameSurname($nameSurname)
    {
        $this->nameSurname = $nameSurname;
        return $this;
    }



    /************************************************************
     * Set DOB
     *
     * @param string $DOB
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDOB($DOB)
    {
        $this->DOB = $DOB;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get DOB
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDOB()
    {
        return $this->DOB;
    }
}
```

<kbd>Post</kbd> entity....

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Posts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Posts", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Posts_Owners_idx", columns={"Owner_id"}),
 *                                     @ORM\Index(name="fk_Posts_Users_idx", columns={"User_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
    /************************************************************
     * Variables
     ************************************************************/
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Postid", type="bigint")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Postid;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Owner
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Owner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Owner_id", referencedColumnName="Ownerid")
     * })
     */
    private $Owner_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Post_desc", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $PostDesc;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Postdate", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $Postdate;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_id", referencedColumnName="Userid")
     * })
     */
    private $User;


    /************************************************************
     * Getters/setters
     ************************************************************/

    /************************************************************
     * Get Postid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getPostid()
    {
        return $this->Postid;
    } 

     /**
     * Set Postid
     *
     * @param integer $Postid
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPostid($Postid)
    {
        $this->Postid = $Postid;
        return $this;
    }


    /************************************************************
     * Get Owner
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Owner
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->Owner_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set Owner
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Owner $Owner
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setOwner(\AppBundle\Entity\Owner $Owner)
    {
        $this->Owner_id = $Owner;
        return $this;
    }


    /************************************************************
     * Get PostDesc
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostDesc()
    {
        return $this->PostDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Set PostDesc
     *
     * @param string $PostDesc
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPostDesc($PostDesc)
    {
        $this->PostDesc = $PostDesc;
        return $this;
    }


    /************************************************************
     * Get Postdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPostdate()
    {
        return $this->Postdate;
    }

    /**  
     * Set Postdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $Postdate
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPostdate($Postdate)
    {
        $this->Postdate = $Postdate;
        return $this;
    }



    /************************************************************
     * Get User
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->User;
    }

     /**
     * Set User
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $User
     *
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\User $User = null)
    {
        $this->User = $User;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

<kbd>Owner</kbd> entity...

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Owners
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Owners", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Owners_communities_idx", columns={"community_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Owner
{
    /************************************************************
     * Variables
     ************************************************************/
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Ownerid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Ownerid;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\community
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\community")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="community_id", referencedColumnName="communityid")
     * })
     */
    private $community;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Owner_desc", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $OwnerDesc;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author_firstname", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $authorFirstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author_surname", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $authorSurname;


    /************************************************************
     * Getters/setters
     ************************************************************/

    /************************************************************
     * Get Ownerid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOwnerid()
    {
        return $this->Ownerid;
    }



    /************************************************************
     * Get OwnerDesc
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOwnerDesc()
    {
        return $this->OwnerDesc;
    }

    /**
     * set OwnerDesc
     *
     * @param string $OwnerDesc
     *
     * @return Owner
     */
    public function setOwnerDesc($OwnerDesc)
    {
        $this->OwnerDesc = $OwnerDesc;
        return $this;
    }

    /************************************************************
     * Get authorFirstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorFirstname()
    {
        return $this->authorFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * set authorFirstname
     *
     * @param string $authorFirstname
     *
     * @return Owner
     */
    public function setAuthorFirstname($authorFirstname)
    {
        $this->authorFirstname = $authorFirstname;
        return $this;
    }

     /************************************************************
     * Get authorSurname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorSurname()
    {
        return $this->authorSurname;
    }

    /**
     * set authorSurname
     *
     * @param string $authorSurname
     *
     * @return Owner
     */
    public function setAuthorSurname($authorSurname)
    {
        $this->authorSurname = $authorSurname;
        return $this;
    }

     /************************************************************
     * Get community
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\community
     */
    public function getcommunity()
    {
        return $this->community;
    }

    /**
     * set community
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\community $community
     *
     * @return Owner
     */
    public function communitiecommunity(\AppBundle\Entity\community $community = null)
    {
        $this->community = $community;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged the ajax script in a javascript debugger to make sure all the variables contain the values you expect?

Comment: I've not used ajax/jquery before and was kindly 'donated' this from someone that I've tried getting to work and adapted according to what I could find online. However in PhpStorm it doesn't flag anything up as being wrong. Is there another way I should be debugging this?

Comment: seem that the jquery selector don't match the class attribute. try with this: `$(document).on('change', '.change-posts-per-owner',...`

Comment: Thanks both - I just checked the debugger and it does find an error: 1) `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and 2) `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.`. I assume the first is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, seems you don't have jQuery included.

Comment: Thanks both - I've added in `.change-posts-per-owner` and I've included `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`... the ajax request now activates but returns its error function. Is there a way I can debug what is wrong with `data`? I have tried `JSON.stringify(data)` but it doesn't give much helpful information that I can see

Comment: Start by pressing F12 on your browser and viewing the network traffic to see what is being transferred between the client and the server.  That should help to narrow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! First of all, there can be several owners ? Several posts for one User ?

`Owners` and `Posts` are strange here. Could you please add your `AppBundle\Entity\User` entity with mapping (annotation, yml, xml). I think there is finally a mistake in UserType..

In you Ajax script, `Ownerid` is well get ?

Test it by doing `console.log(Ownerid)` just after it has been defined.

In order to see Ajax calls and returns, press F12 and go to console panel and after, change owner in your select in order to trigger Ajax call.

Also, `'data-Owner-id': "form.Owner.vars.Owner_id",` is probably wrong because your relation is named `Owners` instead of `Owner`.

Anyway, I finally think that this `data` attribute is unecessary and you can remove it and in your ajax call get `OwnerID` just by `var Ownerid = $(this).val();`. It should be `id` of selected `Owner`.

Add an unique id for your child `<select/>` (for posts) for example : `posts-select`.

In your method called by Ajax (in your controller) you forgot parameter :

```
/**
* @Route("/newUserAjax/{Ownerid}", name="new_user_ajax", options={"expose"=true})
* @ParamConverter("owner", class="AppBundle:Owner", options={"id" = "Ownerid"})
*/
public function newUserAjaxAction(Owner $owner)
{
    $posts = $owner->getPosts(); // I assume that in you Owner entity there is an attribute posts (a OneToMany relation)

    return new JsonResponse($posts);
}
```

In your `success:function(data)` you can do :

```
success:function(data) {
var child = $(document).find('#posts-select');
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            $(child).append('<option value="' + v[itemId] + '">' + v[itemName] + '</option>');
        });
    }
```

Where `id` and `name` are attributes from `Post` entity.

Before adding `<option` elements, be sure to remove those currently displayed by something like :  `$(child).find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();` (first-child being placeholder).

**UDPATE :**

You should install FOSJSRouting Bundle in order to use `expose=true` (in your routing) an `Routing.generate()` (in your ajax script)

```
 $.ajax({
    url:  Routing.generate('new_User_ajax', {id: Ownerid }),
```

Comment: Thansk once again @Delphine :-) I have added in my entities.... I will go home and work through the rest of your answer as soon as I'm back

Comment: Having a look through - I have the code `'data-Owner-id': "form.Owner.vars.Owner_id",` code as mentioned...but I don't understand where/how this is used in the process? I understand `id` and `class` tags but not sure how the `data-owner-id` would be used?

Comment: Going back to your point about `Owners` and `Posts` being strange: `Owners` should be removed - I added it thinking it might help fix things (but didn't). Although `Posts` I think are correct - a `User` can be referenced in many posts

Comment: Ok so.. A user can have an owner and several posts ?..
Remove this line in your twig render view form : `'data-Owner-id': "form.Owner.vars.Owner_id"` (it's useless, no matter why). Forget about `data` attribute..

Just get ownerid in you script by `var Ownerid = $(this).val();`

Comment: Hey Delphine - No unfortunately I haven't :-( I had been trying but still no luck - and now on Symfony3 the FOSJSRouting bundle isn't compatible so far so I haven't been able to carry on trying to get it to work. Is there an alternative to using this bundle?

Comment: Zut.. So, tour url param in our Ajax call should be `"{{ path('new_User_ajax') }}"` if it's in a twig file. In your controller : `/**
* @Route("/newUserAjax/{Ownerid}", name="new_user_ajax", )
*/
public function newUserAjaxAction(Request $request)
{
    
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
    $ownerID  = $request->request->get('id');
//get owner 
    $posts = $owner->getPosts(); // I assume that in you Owner entity there is an attribute posts (a OneToMany relation)
}
    return new JsonResponse($posts);
}` It's not complete, but it's a lead. Maybe we could talk on chat

Comment: Hey @Delphine - that's very kind thank you! How can I get hold of you in chat? Unfortunately I'm only able to try and work on this in the evenings and I'm retty busy with my day job at the moment. In case you're around I'm free now for what it's worth....! :-D

Comment: Ok so.. I've created a chat room : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/97488/why-isnt-this-ajax-call-capturing-the-onchange-event-in-symfony ! I'll be there until 17h30 and I'll can be there from 18h30

Comment: Hey Delphine - thanks for doing this.... I assume you're on "Europe/Paris" time? I've sent a message on there to you - speak later!